# I want to create a call back url using flask api

Tags: python-3.x, flask

1)Geting error 404 The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2)Unable to call data user wise as I have 25 user want to call data for single user

```
 conn = pymysql.connect(host=None, user='root', passwd=None, db='db1')
 heart_data = pd.read_sql('select * from heart',con = conn)
 app = Flask(__name__)
 @app.route('/HRV/<userid>/',methods = ['GET'])
 def HRV(userid):
        db = heart_data[heart_data['userId'] == userid]
        return(db)`
 if __name__ == "__main__":
       `app.run(debug=True)`
```

Comment: can you try to remove the last slash in your url? Your route should look like this:  `@app.route('/HRV/<userid>',methods = ['GET'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trailing slash.

For exzample you have the following code:

```
@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return 'The project page'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'The about page'
```

> The canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. It’s similar to a folder in a file system. If you access the URL without a trailing slash, Flask redirects you to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
>
> The canonical URL for the about endpoint does not have a trailing slash. It’s similar to the pathname of a file. Accessing the URL with a trailing slash produces a 404 “Not Found” error. This helps keep URLs unique for these resources, which helps search engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

Detail info see [Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior — Flask 1.0.2 documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior)